# Bash function used with command and additional parameter

Tags: bash, dialog, functions

I would like to change my repetitive lines into small function and get rid of unnecessary code. 
It can be fuction with `dialog` command which will have the same parameters, but `--msgbox` will be always different. 
How combine strings and execute function in right way ?

So long it looks like this :

```
function DIALOG_OK() {
    local function_name="${FUNCNAME[1]}"
    local msg="${1}"
    dialog --title "Fist boot detected !" --backtitle "HeadlineHere" ${msg}
}
```

Execution:

```
DIALOG_OK --msgbox "\nFist boot configuration wizard detected.\nPlease choose OK to continue.\n" 8 40
```

Output:

```
Error: Expected at least 3 tokens for --msgbox, have 0.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `msg="${1}"`, but `$1` is just the **first** argument to your function call `DIALOG_OK` which is just `--msgbox`.

Use `"$@"` and don't put in an intermediate variable as you will get issues with your quotes:

```
function DIALOG_OK() {
    local function_name="${FUNCNAME[1]}"
    dialog --title "Fist boot detected !" --backtitle "HeadlineHere" "$@"
}
```

or maybe an `alias` is better than a function in your case:

```
alias DIALOG_OK='dialog --title "Fist boot detected !" --backtitle "HeadlineHere"'
```